# Python import errors in Eclipse based IDE - existing module

Tags: python, eclipse, import, module, aptana

First off, I'm pretty new so I hope I hadn't missed anything too trivial.

Here's a small preface with lots of info:
I'm using Windows & Python 2.7.
I've been using an open-source module named pybrain, which I need to change pretty much for my own purposes. So far I've been changing it directly from the python site-packages folder, but I guess it's a pretty messy way to work, so I decided to try and re-do thing so as to launch it from a different folder. 
I've also decided to start using Aptana (which as far as I can gather is Eclipse-based enough for the same solutions to apply) instead of the messier but simpler "Spyder" I've been using so far.

Pybrain is a pretty layered module with lots of different subfolders, e.g.:
pybrain
--> subfolder1
--> subfolder2
...

So far I've figured these out: 
- I've removed the path to the pybrain folder in site-packages from the PYTHONPATH in aptana project. 
- I've added the path to the new project folder.

This works for some imports, namely, the ones that only reference relative paths inside the subfolders, e.g. I can import from things in subfolder1 if I write a module in the main folder. 
However, whenever I try to import things from the other subfolder - I can't use "pybrain" in the hierarchy:
from pybrain.subfolder2 import * 
doesn't work in subfolder1.

And here is my question:
How do I configure "pybrain" to be a usable name in the code, just as it was when I had pybrain in the site-packages folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have added the wrong path to your source folder...

I.e.:

if you have a structure

```
/project
/project/pybrain
/project/pybrain/__init__.py
```

The source folder set should be '/project' (whereas I think you've set /project/pybrain as the source folder)... if that's not the case, please add more information on your folders and what did you set as a source folder...

Comment: Thanks, I've changed the way I access the original package to solve the problem I had.

Answer (score 0):

Probably Aptana has some way to configure the list of folders which are considered source packages as in pycharm and in eclipse-pydev.

In any case, you could access your module using a `.pth` file in your site-packages. This file can be named as you want (p.e. `pybrain.pth`) and should contain only one line with the path to your pybrain folder. See [this](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html#module-site) and [this](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html#modifying-python-s-search-path).

Comment: Actually I already had it as a source package before, and the .pth idea didn't solve my problem...

Comment: the pth file should work. Are you applying it to the original pybrain folder or to the modified one ?. *Try first with the original one before modifications*. Is pybrain automatically generating a pth file when installed?